# How to create a new column with values as - 'some word as prefix' + 'values from another column' in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I tried the following query but it fails :

```
select UserNo , TeamNo  , TeamName = 'Team'+ TeamNo into TableB FROM TableA ;
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy data from one table to another? Do `INSERT INTO t2 SELECT ... FROM t1 ...`

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Or, even worse, links to images.)'

Comment: try *select UserNo , TeamNo  ,  'Team'+ TeamNo as TeamName into TableB FROM TableA ;*

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. In ANSI SQL `+` is a mathematical function and cannot be used for strings.

Comment: Skip the new table, create a view instead. (Storing computed values is a bad idea, will typically lead to data inconsistency.)

Comment: I get an error : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Team' to data type int   when 'Team' + TeamNo as TeamName

Comment: @jarlh ..sorry I dint get that. I am very new to coding.

Comment: ANSI SQL has || for concatenation. You also need to convert the integer value to varchar before you concatenate. , e.g. `'Team' || cast(TeamNo as varchar(11))`. Some dbms products have `CONCAT()` as a function.

Comment: @jarlh ...I try this as well.Learned something new :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
select UserNo, TeamNo, 'Team' + CAST(TeamNo as varchar(10) As TeamName 
into TableB FROM TableA ;
```

It's better to convert the numeric column to varchar before you concatenate it to another column.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Team' to data type int.

Comment: Are you using MySQL?

Comment: Did you try the above query which is updated later to this `select UserNo, TeamNo, ('Team' + CAST(TeamNo as varchar(10)) As TeamName 
into TableB FROM TableA ;` ? The conversion is done from int to varchar, so no error should be shown. Please check.

Comment: I am using MS-SQL (transact-sql)

Comment: Please check the updated query, it will work both in ms sql and MySQL.

Comment: This worked . Thanks a lot . select UserNo, TeamNo, ('Team' + CAST(TeamNo as varchar(10))) as TeamName into TableB FROM TableA ;  So I was missing the conversion part

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `as` instead of `=`. Like next code:

```
, 'Team'+ TeamNo as TeamName
```